# how to redircet VPS ip to the https domain?

Tags: server, nginx, vps, reverse-proxy, odoo

i'am using a VPS ubuntu 18.4 and i have been installed nginx and certbot to redirect the ERP system website form from 8069 to 80
to be linked with the domain name everything is going well
if i write the domian name in browser it's redirct me to secured website but if ip browsers it's gives me security error and it still the ip if i scaped with http not the domian https.

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble reading your question. You typed https://yourdomainname and all was well, but when you typed https://youripaddress then it was not? If so, the certificate has not been issued for the ip address but only for the domain name. Certificates for ip addresses are possible, but rather uncommon, are you sure you need that?

Comment: yes that all i need, is there anyway to mask th ip with the domian , such if i wrote the ip redirect to domain